# request to vCloud via API using python returns 406?

Tags: python, request, vcloud-director-rest-api

Based on vCloud API documentation user suppose to send the next query
`POST https://vcloud.example.com/api/sessions 
Authorization: Basic encoded-credentials
Accept: application/*+xml;version=5.5
Response:
200 OK
x-vcloud-authorization: cn9uYmdugN8E2j96+5Lqrc3YBvFsEgDHXzyfJrJ/6bM=
Content-Type: application/vnd.vmware.vcloud.session+xml;version=5.5`

I am trying to do the same using python, see the method down below

```
def vcloud_send():
vcloud = requests.Session()
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
result = base64.b64encode(b'user@org:password')
headers = {'Authorization': b"encoded login:password",
           'Accept': 'application/*+xml'}
response = vcloud.request('POST', url='https://host/api/session', headers=headers, verify=False)
return response
```

And I get 406

```
<Response [406]>
```

Please tell me why does this happen and what is a reason, because I expect to get a content

Comment: [Edit] your Question and explaine in detail, **why** do you use `payload = '{{...` as `str` instead of `dict` and **why** dou you use `headers=headers` at all.

Comment: @stovfl have edited the question

Comment: Are you aware about Security Risks, using `verify=False`? Didn't see any requirement of using `header`, `Accept` should be default. Read [httpstatuses.com/406](https://httpstatuses.com/406). Try like this [Basic-Authentication or Digest Authentication](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/#basic-authentication)

Comment: Are you logging in with system admin credentials, or as a tenant? Is there a stack trace in the response body with more detail about the 406?